# Bluebird promise not returning

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using Bluebird promise 2.9.25 for a Cordova based app which connect to multiple Bluetooth devices.

I'm having some stability issues. On some instances, a caller calls a function which returns a promise, but although inside I can `console.log()` messages which is about to `resolve()`. But the caller never reach the `then` clause. Subsequently user actions which presses buttons and entering different code path will fail when calling `Promise.map()`. It does not go into the handling function for map.

I only test this part of the code on actual device since it has to do with BLuetooth connectivity. Since it's in Cordova on iOS, it seems weird a lot of time I have trouble getting error messages. The failure look pretty silent to me.

Is there any guess how this could have happened? This doesn't always happen. But it can happen maybe 1 out of 10 right now whenever I enter the page. Or it seems to happen more often when I switch pages really fast.

Comment: Questions about code that doesn't work MUST include the relevant code. It sounds like you have logic or timing issues or a failure to handle errors properly.  But, we would need to see the actual code to offer any specific advice.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you very much for the comment. At this point I just can't seem to isolate the relevant part of the code to post. The code that's showing the problem does not seem to be the cause. Putting a couple of setTimeout between Bluetooth read and writes seemed to alleviate some problems, but not all. And then I updated the iOS Cordova platform and the Bluetooth plugin, and I seemed to dodge the issue completely. :/